# Creating .deb pkg to install in $HOME

Tags: ubuntu, unix, deb, dpkg

I'm new to Linux . I developed application which I want to distribute as deb pkg.
That application designed for user so I need to install it in User's Home directory. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You should check [debreate](https://antumdeluge.github.io/debreate-web/) it's a GUI-based tool for Debian-based packaging.
You can configure your application installation with it.

Answer (score 0):

Debian packages are designed to be installed system-wide. Perhaps you can circumvent this by packaging an installer which the user can run to dump the files into their home directory.